Why is the Android Studio Profiler unable to detect memory allocated by the C++'s new operator?
"I've tried the code below, but the Android Studio Profiler is unable to detect any allocated memory.
char* p = new char[1024];

When I change the code to:
char *p = static_cast<char *>(malloc(100));

the Profiler does detect the 100 bytes allocated by malloc. I don't understand why this is happening. I hope someone can help me.
Android Studio version: Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 3
I expect that the Profiler can detect memory allocated by C++'s new operator as well.
